# Find pairs in an array such that a%b = k , where k is a given integer

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, number-theory

Here is an interesting programming puzzle I came across . Given an array of positive integers, and a number K. We need to find pairs(a,b) from the array such that `a % b = K`.

I have a naive **O(n^2)** solution to this where we can check for all pairs such that a%b=k. Works but inefficient. We can certainly do better than this can't we ? Any efficient algorithms for the same? Oh and it's NOT homework.

Comment: @harold will it make any difference ?

Comment: I thought it did but, but if it does it's not for the reason I thought. It wouldn't have changed the big Oh anyway, it was just an optimization based on modulo being slow - but it's actually always valid.

Comment: worst case - O(n^2) pairs. (4,4,7,7,10,3,3,3,3,3) k=1

Comment: @harold well you can post your solution for both cases

Comment: @MBo - the number of pairs does not prove anything. Inversions are defined in terms of pairs, but you can count them faster than `O(n^2)`.

Comment: You can count them, but you can't list them. The question, as currently worded, seems to imply the latter.

Comment: You can probably list them faster than O(n^2) too, if you can list them as multi-set entries. (that is, as counted pairs).

Comment: @dbaseman and other close-voters, please note that this is not a duplicate. This question is asking for an algorithm for `A%B = K`. The question that's being linked to is asking for an algorithm where `(A+B)%k = 0`

Comment: ... and people who can't even be bothered to read two lines ruin another perfectly fine question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort your array and binary search or keep a hash table with the count of each value in your array.

For a number `x`, we can find the largest `y` such that `x mod y = K` as `y = x - K`. Binary search for this `y` or look it up in your hash and increment your count accordingly.

Now, this isn't necessarily the only value that will work. For example, `8 mod 6 = 8 mod 3 = 2`. We have:

```
x mod y = K => x = q*y + K =>
            => x = q(x - K) + K =>
            => x = 1(x - K) + K =>
            => x = 2(x - K)/2 + K =>
            => ...
```

This means you will have to test all divisors of `y` as well. You can find the divisors in `O(sqrt y)`, giving you a total complexity of `O(n log n sqrt(max_value))` if using binary search and `O(n sqrt(max_value))` with a hash table (recommended especially if your numbers aren't very large).

Answer (score 0):

Treat the problem as having two separate arrays as input: one for the a numbers and a % b = K and one for the b numbers. I am going to assume that everything is >= 0.

First of all, you can discard any b <= K.

Now think of every number in b as generating a sequence K, K + b, K + 2b, K + 3b... You can record this using a pair of numbers (pos, b), where pos is incremented by b at each stage. Start with pos = 0.

Hold these sequences in a priority queue, so you can find the smallest pos value at any given time. Sort the array of a numbers - in fact you could do this ahead of time and discard any duplicates.

```
For each a number
  While the smallest pos in the priority queue is <= a
    Add the smallest multiple of b to it to make it >= a
    If it is == a, you have a match
    Update the stored value of pos for that sequence, re-ordering the priority queue
```

At worst, you end up comparing every number with every other number, which is the same as the simple solution, but with priority queue and sorting overhead. However, large values of b may remain unexamined in the priority queue while several a numbers pass through, in which case this does better - and if there are a lot of numbers to process and they are all different, some of them must be large.

Answer (score 0):

This answer mentions the main points of an algorithm (called *DL* because it uses “divisor lists” ) and gives details via a program, called amodb.py.

Let B be the input array, containing N positive integers.  Without much loss of generality, suppose `B[i] > K` for all `i` and that B is in ascending order.  (Note that `x%B[i] < K` if `B[i] < K`; and where `B[i] = K`, one can report pairs (B[i], B[j]) for all `j>i`.  If B is not sorted initially, charge a cost of `O(N log N)` to sort it.)

In algorithm *DL* and program amodb.py, A is an array with K pre-subtracted from the input array elements. Ie, `A[i] = B[i] - K`.  Note that if `a%b == K`, then for some `j` we have `a = b*j + K` or `a-K = b*j`.  That is, `a%b == K` iff `a-K` is a multiple of `b`.  Moreover, if `a-K = b*j` and `p` is any factor of `b`, then `p` is a factor of `a-K`.

Let the prime numbers from 2 to 97 be called “small factors”.  When N numbers are uniformly randomly selected from some interval [X,Y], on the order of N/ln(Y) of the numbers will have no small factors; a similar number will have a greatest small factor of 2; and declining proportions will have successively larger greatest small factors.  For example, on the average about `N/97` will be divisible by 97, about `N/89-N/(89*97)` by 89 but not 97, etc.  Generally, when members of B are random, lists of members with certain greatest small factors or with no small factors are sub-O(N/ln(Y)) in length.

Given a list Bd containing members of B divisible by largest small factor *p*, *DL* tests each element of Bd against elements of list Ad, those elements of A divisible by *p*.  But given a list Bp for elements of B without small factors, *DL* tests each of Bp's elements against all elements of A.  Example: If `N=25`, `p=13`, `Bd=[18967, 23231]`, and `Ad=[12779, 162383]`, then *DL* tests if any of `12779%18967, 162383%18967, 12779%23231, 162383%23231` are zero.  Note that it is possible to cut the number of tests in half in this example (and many others) by noticing `12779<18967`, but amodb.py does not include that optimization.

*DL* makes `J` different lists for `J` different factors; in one version of amodb.py, `J=25` and the factor set is primes less than 100.  A larger value of `J` would increase the `O(N*J)` time to initialize divisor lists, but would slightly decrease the `O(N*len(Bp))` time to process list Bp against elements of A.  See results below.  Time to process other lists is `O((N/logY)*(N/logY)*J)`, which is in sharp contrast to the `O(n*sqrt(Y))` complexity for a previous answer's method.

Shown next is output from two program runs.  In each set, the first `Found` line is from a naïve O(N*N) test, and the second is from *DL*.  (Note, both *DL* and the naïve method would run faster if too-small A values were progressively removed.) The time ratio in the last line of the first test shows a disappointingly low speedup ratio of 3.9 for *DL* vs naïve method.  For that run, `factors` included only the 25 primes less than 100.  For the second run, with better speedup of ~ 4.4, `factors` included numbers 2 through 13 and primes up to 100.

```
  $ python amodb.py 
  N:  10000   K:  59685 X:  100000   Y:  1000000
  Found 208  matches in 21.854 seconds
  Found 208  matches in 5.598 seconds
  21.854 / 5.598 = 3.904

  $ python amodb.py
  N:  10000   K:  97881 X:  100000   Y:  1000000
  Found 207  matches in 21.234 seconds
  Found 207  matches in 4.851 seconds
  21.234 / 4.851 = 4.377
```

Program amodb.py:

```py
import random, time
factors = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]
X, N = 100000, 10000
Y, K = 10*X, random.randint(X/2,X)
print "N: ", N, "  K: ", K, "X: ", X, "  Y: ", Y
B = sorted([random.randint(X,Y) for i in range(N)])
NP = len(factors);  NP1 = NP+1
A, Az, Bz = [], [[] for i in range(NP1)], [[] for i in range(NP1)]
t0 = time.time()
for b in B:
    a, aj, bj = b-K, -1, -1
    A.append(a)                 # Add a to A 
    for j,p in enumerate(factors):
        if a % p == 0:
            aj = j
            Az[aj].append(a)
        if b % p == 0:
            bj = j
    Bz[bj].append(b)
Bp = Bz.pop()   # Get not-factored B-values list into Bp
di = time.time() - t0; t0 = time.time()
c = 0
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        if a%b == 0:
            c += 1
dq =  round(time.time() - t0, 3); t0 = time.time()
c=0
for i,Bd in enumerate(Bz):
    Ad = Az[i]
    for b in Bd:
        for ak in Ad:
            if ak % b == 0:
                c += 1
for b in Bp:
    for ak in A:
        if ak % b == 0:
            c += 1
dr = round(di + time.time() - t0, 3)
print "Found", c, " matches in", dq, "seconds"
print "Found", c, " matches in", dr, "seconds"
print dq, "/", dr, "=", round(dq/dr, 3)
```